# Execution Stack vs Scope Chain

Tags: javascript

```
function one() {
    function two() {
        alert(i);
    }
    return two; 
}

(function() {
    var i = 3;

    var f = one();

    f(); // Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined
}());
```

The articles I've read say that, when a function is called, a new execution context is added on to the stack and the scope chain is created by traversing up the stack. But surely that would result in 3 being alerted in the above code?

How does it work out the scope chain?

Comment: What's your issue exactly?

Comment: Where exactly did you read that *the scope chain is created by traversing up the stack*? That's not correct.

Comment: Here... http://davidshariff.com/blog/javascript-scope-chain-and-closures/

Comment: "The scope chain property of each execution context is simply a collection of the current context's [VO] + all parent execution context's [VO]."

Comment: Ah OK - that author is talking about the lexical "parentage" relationship. It's not the function call stack, it's the fact that the sequence of functions are nested in the code.

Comment: Then why would he use 'current contexts' in the above quote?

Comment: Well at any given point of execution, there *is* a current context, and what matters for scope is where the current code appeared in the source structure - how and where it was nested inside other scopes. The call stack doesn't affect that.

Comment: @IanWarburton: It sounds like he's describing what the "scope" (or "execution context") is for the function.  In the example in the page, `three()` can access the scope from both `one()` and `two()` since it's defined inside of them.  In your code, `one()` is declared separately, so it (and `two()`) are outside of the scope of `i`.

Comment: Great article... http://dmitryfrank.com/articles/js_closures

Comment: Although the variable name (`i`) is the same inside the self invoking function as well as inside the `one` - the scopes are independent of each other. The traversing will happen - but will go up a level i.e. to global and then check for an `i` at the global level - it won't find any and thus will return `undefined`. Try putting `var i = 123` at the first line of the code snippet and then run it - will return `123`.

Answer (score 3):

The scope chain is determined by the lexical nesting of scopes. The scope *can* be affected dynamically (via `with`), but that causes a lot of problems. It's definitely not the case that the current stack of function activations has anything to do with scope.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `var i = 3;`, you are creating a local variable that exists *only* in the scope of the immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE).

Any functions that are *defined* in that scope can access the variable `i`.

`one()` (and therefore also `two()`) was declared *outside* the scope, so it has no idea what `i` is.  It's looking up its scope chain to `window.i`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The call stack (as mentioned keeps adding an execution context to the top of the stack when a function is invoked) and lexical scope (which allows access to variables from outer scope) are independent of each other.

Lexical scope depends only on where the function is created not where the function is invoked, so in your example function "two" is created inside function "one", so when variable "i" inside function "two" tries to access "i", it tries to find "i" in its own scope first, since there is no "i" defined it will go out to the scope where the function is created in your case its function "one" (not where the function is invoked in anonymous IIFE below) and it couldn't find variable "i" again inside function "one", now since function "one" is defined inside global scope (the default execution context) JS will try to find the value of "i" inside the global scope which results in "undefined".

In order to access variable "i" you need to move function "two" into anonymous IIFE as shown below, function two has outer lexical scope of function "one" which has an outer lexical scope of anonymous IIFE which has i assigned to 3 which is alerted.

```
(function () {
  var i = 3;
function one() {
  function two() {
    alert(i); // will alert 3
  }
  return two;
}
var f = one();
f();
}());
```

Hope this is clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

The call stack and the execution context stack are not the same. A function call adds a level to the call stack, but execution context stacks are not changed. However, the function that you call has a *different* execution context stack.

Each function scope has its own execution context stack which is determined by where the function is created, it doesn't inherit the execution context stack from the calling code.

If you nest functions in each other and only call the inner functions, like in the first example on the page, the call stack and the execution context stack will happen to correspond.

Comment: But a function's execution context is added on top of execution context stack only when its called. So shouldn't they always correspond? Could you please provide some example where they won't?

Answer (score 0):

Execution stack is what happens on hardware (memory), regardless of whatever high level language is running. The scope chain model is managed by specific interpreter to implement programming language features such as functional programming, which itself is another program independent from the one you've written, the sequence of function call stacks via the interpreter is different from the actual order on physical hardware.